# A finite number of probability distributions is always dominated?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, reference-request

I'm working with a statistical model $(\mathcal{Y},\mathcal{P}=\{P_0,P_1\})$. That is, the model only includes 2 probability distributions $P_0$ and $P_1$ on $\mathcal{Y}$.  The context is testing one simple hypothesis ($P_0$) against another ($P_1$). My text then claims that:

> Because $\color{blue}{\text{there are only two probability distributions in the model}}$, $\color{red}{\text{the model is always dominated by some measure $\mu$ (for instance, by $P_0+P_1$)}}$.

Can someone please why the $\color{blue}{\text{blue phrase}}$ implies the $\color{red}{\text{red phrase}}$? Please also give me a reference to learn more about implications like this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mu=P_0+P_1$, then $\mu(A)=P_0(A)+P_1(A)$ so because $P_0$ and $P_1$ are nonnegative, we have $\mu(A)=0$ implies $P_0(A)=P_1(A)=0$. This satisfies the definition of domination. A corollary of this is that each of $P_0$ and $P_1$ admits a density with respect to $\mu$. This is the Radon-Nikodym Theorem, which can be found as Corollary 12.1.2. in Rosenthal's *A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory*.

If you have $P_0,\ldots,P_n$ for some fixed natural number $n$, you can similarly define $\mu=\sum_{j=0}^n P_j$.